# How to get nid and title from a node array

Tags: 8, nodes

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function abc($v) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($v);
  print_r($node);
}
```

The array structure of $node is as given below

> ```
> Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object (
> [in_preview] => 
>
> [values:protected] => Array
>     (
>
>
>    [nid] => Array
>         (
>             [x-default] => 166
>         )
>
>     [vid] => Array
>         (
>             [x-default] => 180
>         )
>
>     [type] => Array
>         (
>             [x-default] => sections
>         )
>
>     [uuid] => Array
>         (
>             [x-default] => 7759efc9-cfff-4d58-b392-8d60b9903323
>         )
>
>     [langcode] => Array
>         (
>             [x-default] => en
>         )
> ```

Comment: A node is an object, not an array. Learn how to use [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of @Hudri `Node` is an object not an array.

In Drupal 8 there are two ways to get the value of a field.

1. `$node->field_name->value`
2. `$node->get("field_name")->getValue()`

In your case you can get the `nid` and `title` like below:

```
$nid = $node->id();
$title = $node->label();
```

or

```
$title = $node->getTitle();
```

To read about objected-oriented programming conventions In Drupal 8 check this blog article: [Drupal 8 API: objected-oriented programming conventions](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2016-10-11/drupal-8-api-objected-oriented-programming-conventions).

Comment: it's not ideal to use magic methods to get the title. There are two better methods, `Node::getTitle()` and `Entity::label()`, that should take precedence

Answer (score 2):

you can get the node id like this :

```
$nid = $node->id();
```

and for the title :

```
$title = $node->label();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the node id and node title values by using Node::load function.

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function abc($v)
{

```
$node = Node::load($v);

$strNodeId =  $node->nid->value;

$strNodeTitle = $node->title->value;

echo 'Id: '.$strNodeId;

echo 'Title: '.$strNodeTitle;
exit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 media items (e.g. Remote Video), use `getName()`